# Understanding private variables in object literals during an HTTP request's life

Tags: node.js

Do CommonJS modules that return an object literal (`module.exports = {...}`) share a single instance across all HTTP requests in a node server?

I'm asking because I have some confusion about private var's in this pattern. For instance:

1. two client's request route/signup at the same time
2. client one's signup module instantiates all its required modules
3. client one's signup module now have values in its private var's.

My question is, will both client be competing for their own private var values since both clients have set private vars to different values depending on their request data being sent.

Comment: Yes, the will all get the same object literal.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB. I'm not going to type out all the chat from IRC, so I'm considering this closed. +)